# Внутри асинхронной функции теряется значение

Tags: node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

Всем привет! Делаю первый серверный проект. Работаю над валидацией данных. Объясню, что я хочу сделать: внутри бд настроена валидация. Отдельно на модели пользователя, отдельно на модели заказа. Я хочу, чтобы из функции создания пользователя возвращались ошибки валидации, если они есть, потом проверялась валидность данных заказа и потом общий список ошибок отправлялся на клиент.
Вот кусок кода:

```
async function getCreateUser(data) {
  const user = await users.findOrCreate({
    where: { email: `${data.email}` },
    defaults: {
      fullname: data.fullname,
      email: data.email,
      phone_number: data.phone,
      town: data.town,
    },
  }).catch((err) => {
    const errorMsgs = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < err.errors.length; i += 1) {
      errorMsgs[err.errors[i].message] = err.errors[i].message;
    }
    console.log('errors in getCreate');
    console.log(errorMsgs);
    return errorMsgs;
  });
  return user.id;
}

async function createNewOrder(data, res) {
  const userId = await getCreateUser(data);
  console.log('log in createOrder: ');
  console.log(userId);
  if (typeof userId === 'object') {
    console.log(userId);
    if (data.rules !== true) {
      userId.rules = 'rules';
    }
    res.json(userId, 400);
  } else {
    await orders.create({
      user_id: null,
      summ: await getPackPrice(data.package),
      rules: data.rules,
    }).then(() => {
      res.json(201);
    }).catch((err) => {
      const errorMsgs = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < err.errors.length; i += 1) {
        errorMsgs[i + 1] = err.errors[i].message;
      }
      console.log(errorMsgs);
      res.json(400);
    });
  }
}
```

Если можно сделать оптимальнее, то с удовольствием выслушаю ваши предложения. Однако в чем проблема сейчас: в создании пользователя все прекрасно валидируется, но уже в создании заказа, userId в консоль выводит undefined. Вот скрин консоли

[image: скрин]

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Причастных с праздником!

Comment: Эм, а в чём вопрос? У тебя какая-то ошибка (отловленная в `catch`) так что непонятно какой userId ты пытаешься вернуть.

Comment: в catch отловлена ошибка валидации. Я хочу вернуть либо текст ошибки, либо, если ошибок нет, значение userId

Comment: `catch((err) => {` По умолчанию, `err` это объект, у которого есть ключи `message` и `stack`. Там нет `.errors.length`. Выведите в консоль err и посмотрите структуру данных. Такое ощущение, что у вас и `catch` ломается, вот `undefined` и получаете

Comment: @Swad Если несколько ошибок валидации, то sequelize возвращает массив из ошибок объединённых типом {validation error} и соответственно там есть длина. Вопрос в том, что в return должен отправляться или {object}, или {integer}. И он отправляется. Но на выходе значение {undefined}

Comment: А ) Стоп, понял ) Вы в функции `getCreateUser` результат записываете в `user`. Судя по выводу, из catch вы возвращаете { fullname: 'XX' }, а далее из функции уходит результат `user.id`, однако в user нет ключа id

Comment: @SwaD {user.id} - внешний ключ и автоинкремент, он автоматически создается БД. В случае  отсутствия ошибок должен возвращаться ID. Если есть ошибки(пустое поле в fullname, например), то должен вернуться объект с значением поля ошибки. В catch такой объект отображается, но после return он пропадает

Comment: Никуда он не пропадает. Выведите перед `return user.id;` саму переменную `user` и увидите, что лежит ровно то, что вернулось из `catch`. А из catch не возвращается ключ id

Comment: @SwaD переместите, пожалуйста в чат обсуждение, мне репутации не хватает)
Если посмотреть функцию getCreateUser, то user_id должен возвращаться ТОЛЬКО в случае отсутсвия ошибок. Если хоть одна ошибка есть, то возвращается не user_id, а объект с ошибками. Этот объект перед return-ом выводится в консоль(скрин). Когда он возвращается в createNewOrder, то значение этого объекта undefined(скрин)

Comment: В случае ошибки вы записываете её в `user`. А потом пишете `return user.id` (31 строка). Конечно никакого `id` в объекте с ошибкой нет.

Comment: @Alexey Ten посмотрите, пожалуйста, код, а не только скриншот. В случае ошибки я создаю объект errorMsgs и записываю туда все сообщения об ошибках и возвращаю объект. До return user_id программа не доходит из-за return-a раньше по коду

Comment: Доходит-доходит. Вставьте console.log прямо перед return user.id  и убедитесь самостоятельно

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но из асинхронных функций `return` не возвращает результат, а передает далее по цепочке вызова. Можно написать так `const user = fn().then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a}).then(a => {return ++a})` и отработают все `then`, а результатом в user Будет записан результат последней функции. Почитайте про [цепочку промисов](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-chaining)

Comment: @smilezz этот return errorMsgs находится во **внутренней** стрелочной функции. При выполнении return завершается **внутренняя** функция и управление **возвращается** обратно во **внешнюю** функцию getCreateUser (в то место, в котором стоит await), а дальше следующей строкой в ней успешно выполняется `return user.id`. Вместо того, чтобы теоретизировать и спорить, вы за прошедшие полчаса могли бы успеть сделать `console.log(user)` и на практике вживую увидеть, что всё там доходит)

Comment: Я не спорил, а пытался объяснить) Понял свою ошибку, спасибо, добрые люди!

Comment: Вообще, если уж используется await, то можно было бы не лезть в методы промисов и перехватить ошибку в строке await через банальный try/catch — код стал бы читабельнее и без путаницы с вложенными стрелочными функциями

Comment: @andreymal СПАСИБО большое! Действительно с try catch намного удобнее и проще! Все получилось!